# Can I use Show Report Filter Pages with multiple filter values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

[Image of the PivotTable & Show Report Filter Pages dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz2sl.png)

I have data in a pivot table with 2 report filters chosen. I would like to use the Show Report Filter Pages functionality with both of the filters selected, ideally it would generate the sheet names like this: Sales Person - Difference

Is there a way to do this currently?

Comment: Try to use Slicer in PivotTable: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-slicers-to-filter-data-249f966b-a9d5-4b0f-b31a-12651785d29d

Comment: @Lee I could do this and have the slicer linked across all of the reports (I've played around with this somewhat), but unfortunately it's not entirely what I need.